# How to add relation between two tables in Mysql using Mysql control center

Tags: mysql

I want to create two tables with one to many relations. I use MySql Control center,but I did not find to add foreign key.I do not want to use console commands,How can I do? I also want to use transation so I use InnoDB table type, How can I add relation between two tables in Control Center.Is there another GUI software to handle Mysql?Pls tell me.

Comment: You can do this with phpMyAdmin, but that requires having an apache server (or other web server) set up to access the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

You should check SQLYog by Webyog
http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php#sqlyog

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give a try to **MySQL Workbench 5.1 OSS** it can do the job for, after created the entity you just export it as SQL format or XML as you wish, then import to your mysql database.

Folow the link [Download Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)